How to Implement Voice Interaction Animations in a Flutter App?
I'm developing a personal assistant app in Flutter that records your voice and provides responses, similar to ChatGPT. I want to add animations that visually indicate when the user is speaking and when the bot is responding. Specifically, I'm looking for animations like the circle that animates with the voice input and reflects the speaking activity.
User Speaking: A circle that animates as the user speaks.
Bot Responding: A similar animation when the bot is responding.
Has anyone implemented something like this in Flutter? Are there any existing packages or custom solutions that could help achieve this effect? Any code examples or guidance on implementing these animations would be greatly appreciated!

yep, custom solution is CustomPaint widget - with it you can draw whatever circle animation you like

class CirclePainter extends CustomPainter {
  final double volume;

  CirclePainter(this.volume);

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    Paint paint = Paint()
      ..color = Colors.blue.withAlpha((volume * 15).clamp(0, 255).toInt())
      ..style = PaintingStyle.fill;

    double radius = (volume * 1.5).clamp(50, 150);
    canvas.drawCircle(size.center(Offset.zero), radius, paint);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CirclePainter oldDelegate) => volume != oldDelegate.volume;
}

You can customize it.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
